# Is there peer-reviewed, scientific research that compares productivity of employees working from home vs. an office?

Tags: work-environment, productivity, telecommute, offices

I hear lots of anecdotes and opinions about the relative productivity of working from home vs in an office. But is there any scientific research that compares the productivity of these two working models?

*Note: I am aware that "productivity" is vague and hard to measure. But there are any number of possible metrics one could use as a proxy for "productivity", and I am interested in research that looks at such metrics*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be asking for pointers to off-site resources rather than solutions to a specific problem, and Stack Exchange is really set up for the latter.

Comment: Another caveat: peer-reviewed =/= credible. It's better than any one person's own experience and anecdotal evidence but that's about it.

Comment: Thirdly, the major problem with measuring productivity of working at home is that such measurement does not include the added burden that the manager has. It assumes that the rest of the organization is neutral regarding home vs. office productivity. Managers have a much harder time with remote work as it requires better definition of the work needed and far better definition of how to define success in doing that work. This is why management is pushing return to the office.

Answer (score 2):

If you google your own question "**scientific research that compares productivity of employees working from home vs. an office**", you will find this result:

> Stanford University researchers doing a longitudinal study comparing productivity at different time periods found that remote workers were 5% more efficient than office-based ones in the summer of 2020. But this number improved to 9% by summer 2022. Why? Because all of us learned how to be better at remote work.

In addition to that search result, you will also find a link to an article from **Forbes** magazine that discusses and analyzes the paragraph above in more details.

Comment: I would suggest using google scholar rather than generic google. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=scientific+research+that+compares+productivity+of+employees+working+from+home+vs.+an+office

Comment: Could you please add a full reference to the paper you quoted? I found many papers, but not the one you quoted.